# python multiprocessing locks inside async function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this non-async code which is running in async function

Basically ast.NodeTransformer transformations

```py
def is_lgf_in_tree(tree: ast.Expression) -> bool:
    """Walk tree while lgf call is not found"""
    for n in ast.walk(tree):
        if (
            isinstance(n, ast.Call)
            and isinstance(n.func, ast.Name)
            and n.func.id == "lgf"
        ):
            return True
    return False

def transform(lgf: LGF, nested_lgfs: dict[str, LGF]) -> Tuple[LGF, ast.Expression]:
    transformer = LGFTransformer(nested_lgfs=nested_lgfs)
    tree = ast.parse(lgf.expression, mode="eval")

    while is_lgf_in_tree(tree):  # make flat layer by layer
        tree = transformer.visit(tree)

    return lgf, tree
```

In case if NodeTransformer code could help

```py
class LGFTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, nested_lgfs: Dict[str, LGF]):
        super().__init__()
        self.nested_lgfs = nested_lgfs

    def visit_Call(self, node: ast.Call):
        if not isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
            return self.generic_visit(node)
        if not (node.func.id == "lgf" and len(node.args) == 2 and len(node.keywords) == 0):
            return self.generic_visit(node)
        if not isinstance(node.args[0], ast.Constant):
            return self.generic_visit(node)

        _args = [arg.value for arg in node.args if isinstance(arg, ast.Constant)]
        lgf = self.nested_lgfs.get(node.args[0].value, None)
        if not lgf:
            return node

        exp = ast.parse(lgf.expression, mode="eval")
        return exp.body
```

#### Example of straightforward code

```py
    results = []
    for lgf in initial_lgfs:
        results.append(transform(lgf, lgfs_by_name))
```

[image: profiling 1]

#### Example of my attempt to multiprocess it

```py
    from multiprocess.pool import Pool
    arguments = [(lgf, lgfs_by_name) for lgf in initial_lgfs]
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(transform, arguments)
```

[image: profiling 2]

My idea is to run ast module in parallel to lower computation time

Results are unpleasant for me. What can I change/play with to transform multiple functions with ast.NodeTransformer.
Why those new processes are trying to wait on each other. Is it because I share mutual data? Or async function is the problem?
Could `deepcopy` solve it?

What am I missing and why is it trying to synchronize processes?

EDIT: I figured out that this massive delay is caused by process creating stuff.
Is there a way to minimize this overhead? I tried to change 'fork' method of process creating to 'spawn' but it didn't help

Comment: I don't know which OS you're running on.  I suspect that you're seeing the runtime profile of the main thread.  And yes, pretty much the only thing the main thread is doing is sending data to the other threads and waiting for them to send back results.

Comment: @FrankYellin so you are saying that the only problem is the mutual data between processes? Could deepcopy solve it or I should change the approach?

I'm running linux.The problem is that from 0.8s it turned out to be 15s.
I thought all the data will be copied to new process, then calculated and result will be sent back to main thread.

Comment: I'm saying there is no bug.  You're seeing exactly what you'd expect to see if all the work was being done in other threads.  Is the code running faster?

Comment: @FrankYellin as seen from my profiling screenshots and messages - no. Code is running much slower than I expected. From 0.8s it's taking 15s after multiprocessing example

Comment: Does using the function `starmap_async` change a thing?

Comment: @Jib I didn't try it, but how could it help? In my understanding async functions are useful when you want to create a separate worker and then fetch results later as non-blocking operation. But the problem with massive overhead of process-creation is still persists. Probably I didn't describe my problem well. I'm doing this in fastapi process to speed up one of the endpoints so this overhead might be related to it. Maybe I should consider using celery for that type of a job.